# How to extract an unknown archive file? Currently Im trying to open *.pak (P5CK)

Tags: linux, hex

I have a console game called Timesplitters Future Perfect(iso file). I were able to extract and got bunch of files. *.pak being one type I would like to open and see.

I opened up a hex editor and saw that everyone started with P5CK with gibberish afterward.

How to extract an unknown archive file?

Answer (score 2):

Xentax is a good reference on game format RE in general and they seem to already have some info on this one, as well as a QickBMS script:

http://wiki.xentax.com/index.php/Time_Splitters_Future_Perfect

see also [the forum thread](http://forum.xentax.com/viewtopic.php?t=1239).

for general approaches on RE of unknown archive formats, check this blog:

https://hackernoon.com/reverse-engineering-visual-novels-101-d0bc3bf7ab8